# Connecting a Swift App to an AWS Database

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am new to iOS Development and Swift, I don't have any formal experience with it. Just where I have read about some topics and messed around inside of Xcode. For a project I am working on, I need to connect to an AWS DynamoDB database to a Swift app. However, I can't really find any clear answers or if it is even possible. Any help would be great!

Comment: Nowadays there's an SDK for almost everything. Amazon has an AWS SDK with loads of modules. Have you checked there for anything that might work for your needs? https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios

Comment: I've heard of some things regarding SDKs but I will be sure to check them out and look more into it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

AWS Guru here.

Reading your question, **Amplify** is your solution.

> **AWS Amplify** is a set of tools and services that can be used together or on their own, to help front-end web and mobile developers
> build scalable full stack applications, powered by AWS. With Amplify,
> you can configure app backends and connect your app in minutes, deploy
> static web apps in a few clicks, and easily manage app content outside
> the AWS console.

###### How can Amplify help you with connecting DynamoDB to your iOS project?

AWS Amplify DataStore provides a faster, easier app data modeling with real-time and offline capabilities, powered by AWS AppSync and Amazon DynamoDB

To get started, Follow the [Getting started - iOS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/ios/)

Here's an example of how you can use GraphQL and AWS Amplify to build a blazingly fast backend:

```
Amplify.API.query(request: .paginatedList(YourSchema.self)) { event in
           switch event {
           case .success(let result):
               switch result {
               case .success(let data):
                // Use data
                
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
               }
           case .failure(let error):
               print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
           }
       
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and help! Also, will it matter if our app isn't serverless? If that doesn't matter, will Amplify aid in connecting to our database set up in AWS?

Comment: Amplify uses Cloud Formation to setup a stack of resources that your app will use, including a new dynamoDB table, and GraphQL using App Sync, They pretty much setup everything with the cli command “Amplify Configure” and leave the rest to you. CRUD’ing data